# Querying PostgreSQL DB with Google "get.bounds()" coordinates

Tags: postgis, google-maps, geodjango

I am trying to only display markers on a Google Map that are in the current map bounds and then update the markers when the map moves. The difficulty I am running into is querying my database to pull out and return the data to the front end.

Right now it is just returning an empty array.

I'm not super familiar with DjangoGIS but from following a raft of SO guides and the docs I believe I am on the right track...

Here is my database query (using Django):

```
def marker_info(request):
    
    template_name = 'testingland/electra.html'
    neLat = request.GET.get('neLat', None)
    neLng = request.GET.get('neLng', None)
    swLat = request.GET.get('swLat', None)
    swLng = request.GET.get('swLng', None)
    ne = (neLat, neLng)
    sw = (swLat, swLng)

    xmin = sw[1]
    ymin = ne[0]
    xmax = sw[1]
    ymax = ne[0]
    bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

    geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

    qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(geolocation__coveredby=geom)[0:20] 
    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
            for cafe in qs
    ], safe=False)
```

And here is the Ajax call that sends the `getBounds()` data to the backend:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/electra/marker_info/',
                data: {
                  'neLat': parseFloat(lat0),
                  'neLng': parseFloat(lng0),
                  'swLat': parseFloat(lat1),
                  'swLng': parseFloat(lng1)
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  setTimeout(function(){

                  console.log(data);

                  }, 3000);
                }
              });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by changing the indexes in the `views.py` code.

```
def marker_info(request):
    
    template_name = 'testingland/electra.html'
    neLat = request.GET.get('neLat', None)
    neLng = request.GET.get('neLng', None)
    swLat = request.GET.get('swLat', None)
    swLng = request.GET.get('swLng', None)
    ne = (neLat, neLng)
    sw = (swLat, swLng)

    xmin = float(sw[1])
    ymin = float(sw[0])
    xmax = float(ne[1])
    ymax = float(ne[0])
    bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
    print(bbox)

    geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

    qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(geolocation__coveredby=geom)[0:20] 
    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
            for cafe in qs
    ], safe=False)
```